# BIRT eclipse - remove duplicate values in a column - ROWSPAN

Tags: javascript, eclipse, report, birt

I have a used Insert group option on a data point (Shade) and rows are group based on that value.

[image]

Last column(Total Than) is the sum of second column(Than).

I have used aggregate to calculate sum and its values are repeated for every row.
Similarly in ITEM column i want to display once per shade group but its also being repeated for every row within shade group.

Is there a way achieve this in BIRT, I want to have single value in TOTAL THAN and ITEM columns per shade group. Its similar to rowspan property in HTML.

Answer (score -1):

I think the sum is printed for each row because the aggregation is in the group's detail row:

[image: detail row]

If that's the problem, it should be enough to move the aggregation to the group's footer row:

[image: aggregation in group footer]

If there is currently no group footer, you can add it via the outline:

[image: insert group footer row]